# Could not find class 'com.zgl.greentest.gen.DaoMaster$DevOpenHelper', referenced from method xxx.db.GreenDaoManager.<init>

Tags: java, android

I used GreenDao 3.0 in my Android project, but when I ran the project, it crashed and showed me this. How can I fix it? I used API 17.

ps: when I used API 25 and  Nexus 6,  it  can  run.  But  I  need  adapter other  lower API  and other phones.

```
04-13 05:55:55.573 27953-27953/ E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.gen.DaoMaster$DevOpenHelper', referenced from method xx.db.GreenDaoManager.<init>
04-13 05:55:55.582 27953-27953/xx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.zgl.greentest.gen.DaoMaster$DevOpenHelper
       at xx.db.GreenDaoManager.<init>(GreenDaoManager.java:22)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error:(22, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_e1bngbb2ptnb5q5bumdzqty40$_run_closure3@168d59a7] on root project 'PreSchoolers' of type org.gradle.api.Project. Open File

---

Answer is
/*android

```
    {
compileSdkVersion 23
```

}*/

not found in android studio

Comment: thanks.  I  set it  to 19  , it  led  another problem  Error:(5) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.    How ever,  now  I can  know  what  the cause it is.